# Find difference between two sets of records

Tags: sql

I have a set of data on sql server something like:

```
ID ID_Invoice Article Quantity Status
1  10         carrot  10       null
2  10         carrot  5        C
3  10         onion   8        null
4  10         onion   4        C
5  11         tomato  20       null
6  11         tomato  18       C
7  11         onion   2        null
8  11         onion   1        C
```

It means that a customer ordered 10 carrots and 8 onions (on one invoice) but actually received only 5 carrots and 4 onions. If status is null then it is original quantity, if status is C then it is corrected quantity

I need to generate a table like

```
ID ID_Invoice Article Quantity 
1  10         carrot  -5       
2  10         onion   -4
3  11         tomato  -2
4  11         onion   -1
```

which shows the difference between ordered quantity and real quantity on each invoice. I have no idea how to begin. Any help deeply appreciated :)

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: So you say that the tuple `ID_Invoice, Article, Status` fields form a unique key, and there is always a row with `Status = NULL`, but the `Status = C` row is optional?

Comment: don't disappear after posting a question

Answer (score 8):

Option with simple [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression without excessive JOIN

```
SELECT ID_Invoice, Article, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status IS NULL 
  THEN -1 * Quantity ELSE Quantity END) AS Quantity
FROM dbo.test38
GROUP BY ID_Invoice, Article
```

Result:

```
ID_Invoice Article Quantity 
10  carrot  -5
10  onion   -4
11  onion   -1
11  tomato  -2
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a538f/1)

Comment: @Alexander Fedorenko: Just for **curiosity** can you explain [Why](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7a77/1), i.e if a customer **receives more than its oredred** quantity. And hence how to Modify your **query**.

Comment: @Luv I don't quite understand why need change request?If Quantity is positive then recieved more than ordered and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify, which RDBMS you're using, but my answer is ANSI-SQL standard compliant :) Works with every valid RDBMS out there.

```
SELECT
yt1.ID_Invoice, 
yt1.Article,
yt2.Quantity - yt1.Quantity AS Quantity
FROM
yourTable yt1
INNER JOIN yourTable yt2 ON yt1.ID_Invoice = yt2.ID_Invoice 
                            AND yt1.Article = yt2.Article 
                            AND yt2.Status = 'C'
WHERE
yt1.Status IS NULL
```

This answer is asuming, there's **always** a record with Status NULL and corresponding row with status 'C'. If this is not the case, you'd have to adjust it like this:

```
SELECT
yt1.ID_Invoice, 
yt1.Article,
CASE WHEN yt2.Quantity IS NULL THEN yt1.Quantity ELSE yt2.Quantity - yt1.Quantity END AS Quantity
FROM
yourTable yt1
LEFT JOIN yourTable yt2 ON yt1.ID_Invoice = yt2.ID_Invoice 
                            AND yt1.Article = yt2.Article 
                            AND yt2.Status = 'C'
WHERE
yt1.Status IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 **Good** and **Effecient** answer. I was trying to answer when I saw your **answer :P**

Comment: > This answer is asuming, there's always a record with Status NULL and corresponding row with status 'C'. If this is not the case, you'd have to adjust it like this:

Answer (score 2):

Least resource intensive:

```
SELECT id_invoice
, article
, org_quantity
, new_quantity
, new_quantity - org_quantity diff
FROM (SELECT id_invoice
      , article
      , max(CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN quantity else null END) org_quantity
      , max(CASE WHEN status = 'C' THEN quantity else null END) new_quantity
      FROM   orders
      GROUP BY id_invoice
      , article)
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f96adf/14

Comment: No, it won't. The `DECODE()` of MySQL for example does something entirely different than what you want to do here.

Comment: I noticed (i'm so used to Oracle), i updated the answer for sqlserver

Answer (score 1):

So first of all you have to separate the actual from the ordered by making 2 queries and then you have to left join the orders to the actual .. something like this

```
select 
   Recived.ID, 
   Recived.ID_Invoice,
   Recived.Article,
   Recived.Quantity - Ordered.Quantity as Quantity
from
   (select * from dataTable where Status is null) as Ordered
   left join (select * from  dataTable where Status = 'C')  as Recived on (Ordered.ID_Invoice = Recived.ID_Invoice and Ordered.Article = Recived.Article )
```

NOTE! you will be better if you have an id for each article to use in the "left join" instead of comparing varchars.

**Here is a fiddle example:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16666/1

Comment: Actually I'm using product ID as number, just thought that using some real names in my example could make it easier to analyse :)